# Direct sums commuting with direct products (in a weak sense)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was recently wondering about the following

**Question**: Can we find a field $k$ and sets $I,J$ such that there is *no* isomorphism $\bigoplus_{i \in I} \prod_{j \in J} k \cong \prod_{j \in J} \bigoplus_{i \in I} k$ of vector spaces (i.e. such that the dimensions differ)?

If so, then the question becomes: can we do this for *every* $k$?

Note I am *not* asking if the canonical comparison morphism is an isomorphism; there are easy counterexamples for when that is not the case (c.f. the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686727/direct-product-commutes-with-direct-sum)).

My main motivation is to strengthen the counterexamples alluded to in the line above and counterexamples to the functor $V \otimes -: \mathrm{Vect}_k \to \mathrm{Vect}_k$ (for some fixed $V \in \mathrm{Vect}_k$) preserving arbitrary products. Also, we can show that coproducts and products needn't commute (even in the weak sense above!) in more general categories of modules by considering things like torsion, but I couldn't cook up an example for something as nice as $k$.